# How to get pnpm store directory

Tags: pnpm

Is there any way how to check directory/path of pnpm store?

I know you can set it with `npm config set store /path/to/.pnpm-store`, but `npm config get store` in my case returns `undefined`, which I guess means to pnpm to use some default, but where can I find this default value?

Comment: The closest answer below is @Eric. Be careful, by default pnpm will use a different folder for every partition... I discovered this myself, googled, and found this question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems like as of v3.0.1, you cannot get it. pnpm should probably update `pnpm get store` so that it returns the default location.

As of v3, the pnpm store is located at `~/.pnpm-store` by default.

You could also open the file `node_modules/.modules.yaml` in your project. It will contain a field called "store" with the location of the store that was used to hardlink packages to your project.

## Update 2022:

As of v7, refer to @renardesque's or @nouvist's answer's below.

Answer (score 48):

Nowadays you can do

```bash
pnpm store path
```

which, according to pnpm's documentation:

> Returns the path to the active store directory.

The default locations of the store are:

- If the `$XDG_DATA_HOME` env variable is set, then `$XDG_DATA_HOME/pnpm/store`
- On Windows: `~/AppData/Local/pnpm/store`
- On macOS: `~/Library/pnpm/store`
- On Linux: `~/.local/share/pnpm/store`

Related docs: https://pnpm.io/npmrc#store-dir

Comment: Note that pnpm must also be able to create a hard link from this location to your project directory. If this is not possible, such as in a Docker container with a bind mount, it will instead use the shortest path. This will likely end up being $BIND_MOUNT/.pnpm-store. More info: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/2719#issuecomment-665319474.

Answer (score 16):

previously, pnpm store is located on user home folder.

```
Linux   : ~/.pnpm-store
Windows : C:\Users\YOUR_NAME\.pnpm-store
macOS   : ~/.pnpm-store
```

but from now on ([`v7.0.0`](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/releases/tag/v7.0.0)), pnpm store is located on different folder. it will located on `$XDG_DATA_HOME` on Linux, and `%LOCALAPPDATA%` on Windows. take a look to [this issue](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/2574).

```
Linux   : ~/.local/share/pnpm/store (default)
Windows : C:\Users\YOUR_NAME\AppData\Local\pnpm\store
macOS   : ~/Library/pnpm/store
```

or, you can check where is located with [`pnpm store path`](https://pnpm.io/cli/store#path) command

Answer (score 4):

**Possible locaiton:**

- `~/.pnpm-store`
  If project is on the **same** partition as *user home*.
- `$partition_root/.pnpm-store`
  If project is on **different** partition as *user home*.

**Why not just use** `~/.pnpm-store`:

- On linux/mac, pnpm use hard link to reuse file.
- And hard link, can be created only on the same partition.

Comment: This is absolutely correct! I found via the resource monitor that it was writing to /.pnpm-store on a different partition!

Answer (score 1):

Content-addressable store is at: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pnpm\store\v3

Virtual store is at:
node_modules/.pnpm